# Need to suspend RSS feed while repairing missing old post

Tags: email, rss, notifications

Some old posts were accidentally removed from my self hosted site.

I started replacing them from back-ups, but the people who subscribe to my WordPress Feed (and email notification) complained they were being spammed with old posts.

Is there a way to turn off both the RSS feed and the email notification the next time I restore missing posts?

This needs to be temporary. There are disable RSS plug-ins, but they seem to be about killing RSS altogether rather than stopping it temporarily.

Comment: there is no difference between killing RSS and temporarily stopping it ( aka temporarily killing it ), just remove the thing that killed RSS when you're done ( and stop changing the post modified times on your posts and spamming your RSS subscribers ). Have you tried only restoring the missing posts instead of restoring all posts?

Comment: I've been carefully restoring posts one-by-one. I needed to delete a whole bunch of them, was over enthusiastic and removed too many.